# string.substring(1) give different results on different sites with same html

Tags: javascript, substring

I'm using substring(1) to get the last character off of an href attribute.

I'm talking javascript. On my development site, everything works great and the href http://www.mysite.come/page/#B returns B and all is well.

On the live version of the site, the same substring(1) on the same href returns ttp://www.mysite.com/page/#B - it takes off the first character and returns the rest.

I have no idea why it does this. I've used this same script on multiple sites with no issues. The only thing possibly related is that the dev site is running a newer version of jquery (1.8.1) and the live is on 1.7.1.

I used substr(-1,1) instead and everything works fine, but I'd like to know if someone can tell me why I got 2 different results from the same input.

Thanks!

**Extra Info**

I've been using the OrganicTabs script from CSS Tricks for a while now (http://css-tricks.com/organic-tabs/) and never had a problem with it until recently. I tracked it down to the substring line: 

`var curList = base.$el.find("a.current").attr("href").substring(1)`

An example of one of the links I'm this script is targeting:
`<a href="#B"></a>`

I have modified the script to use substr instead, but I don't know why I would get inconsistent results with substring.

Comment: `substring(1)` should return the string without its first character. (As it does on your 'live' server.) If you have different results then you are executing substring NOT on the same input. Can you show us the code?

Comment: According to the following what you got for the live version was "correct" in that it returned everything from the string beginning at index 1: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring

Comment: looks like you're using `window.location.hash.substring(1);` in one place and `window.location.substring(1);` in the other.

Comment: To get the last character, you probably want to be using `string.substr(-1)`, not `string.substring(1)`.

Comment: modified with a little more informaiton

Comment: Marcell you were right, I failed to notice that my live site was using the full URL but my dev site only held the "#B" as the href. I don't really know why, but substring was not being used on the same input in both places. The world seems more sane now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The href you are reading locally, is storing only the hash part of the url,
while for some reason the Live website href's have the whole url

`<a href="#B">Link</a>` vs `<a href="http://www.mysite.come/page/#B">Link</a>`

The substring function is working as expected, since `substring(1)` should return everything but the first character.

Check how you generate your urls

**EDIT**: The best solution is to get the substring starting from the hash (excluding it), which covers both cases, as well as cases where the hash is longer than 1 character

`href.substring(href.indexOf("#")+1)`

Comment: I realized that my local site is non www and the live site is. Could that make a difference? I wouldn't think so...

Comment: the www should not matter. what matters is whether the hrefs have full or relative urls, as explained above.

Comment: You are absolutely right, the live site is using the full URL and for some reason the dev site is only storing the hash. and thanks for recommending the substring that covers more scenarios!

Answer (score 1):

`String.prototype.substring(n [,...])` returns the first `n` characters from the string if `n` is positive, not the last. You need `substr(-1)` for this.

See:

- MDN: [`substr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) vs. [`substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)